# Python Virtualenv on Windows 10 | Broken after Blue Screen

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

I've had Python and virtualenv installed for many months and they both worked without any issues.

Yesterday I put my laptop (Dell XPS 13) to sleep and when I turned it on it gave me the blue screen of death, rebooting several times and attempting to fix issues. It failed to fix the issues and to restore, but after turning it off and on again it seemed to work fine.

Then I tried accessing my Django project by going into `cd Scripts` and `activate` in my virtualenv and it gave me the following error:

`'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I did some research and found that I needed to check my environment variables, however these seem to be fine:
[image]

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some `virtualenv` files have been lost or corrupted.

Try to initialize the `virutalenv` again.